# Vertex colors with skin modifier

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, vertex-colors

I have some curves that I want to render in Cycles; these are not blender curves, instead they are composed of a set of vertices, each having a color, and edges (but no faces).

Using the skin modifier, the generated geometry is exactly what I want, but the vertex colors are not propagated to the skin surface...

As an example (using Meshlab), at the left is what I want, at the right is what I have. Note that I can have colors way more varied than what is shown here.

[image]

**How can I keep the vertex colors in the skin modifier ?**

If this is not possible, then how can I render curves with colors in Cycles ?

[image]

Comment: It also doesn't work with the screw modifier, apparently vertex colors don't work without faces, :( vertex groups work though